# Chazal on pronounciation (according to Koren)

Tags: prayer-book, pronunciation, aleph-bet-letters, chazal

In his introduction to the Koren siddur, Eliyahu Koren claims:

> [A window thou shalt make to the ark](https://www.sefaria.org/Genesis.6.16?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en),” says God to Noah, and our
> sages took this also to mean that the correct pronunciation of the
> words is an embellishment to the prayers.

Does anyone know to which "sages" he is referring to and where I can find this opinion?

Comment: I’m interested to know how this passuk would have anything to with pronouncing words correctly

Comment: @ezra תיבה can mean a word

Comment: [Welcome to MiYodeya](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) Lawrence and thanks for this first question. Great to have you learn with us!

Comment: From the Midrash Tanchuma Buber

> AND YOU ARE TO MAKE A WINDOW (for enlightenment) The Hebrew word for WINDOW here (tsohar) can also carry the connotation of enlightenment

And look in Baal Shem Tov, Noach 15:1 which connects teivah to the words of prayer